# HP Networking Switch CLI Comments?

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, cli

Is there a comment character or do-nothing command in the HP CLI environment?

I'm looking for an equivalent of the exclamation mark (!) in Cisco IOS.

Comment: There isn't one. However, if you look at the on-device config, it starts with `; ...`

Comment: I saw, but it doesn't work the way I want it to when pasting a configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there's no direct equivalent to the Cisco IOS "!" to add comment lines to an HP ProCurve switch config file, you can achieve a similar result by using multiple "alias" commands within the config file, with a final "no alias" command at the end of the script to tidy things up:

```
alias COMMENT "Some procurve configuration comment line here"
...
alias COMMENT "Second line of comment"
...
no alias COMMENT
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to tell you that I believe the answer is no; you can't just insert a comment wherever you want on Procurves.  However, for what it's worth, there is a handy way to [configure "friendly" port names](http://techblog.rezitech.com/how-to-view-and-set-port-names-on-hp-procurve-switch/) so you can at least add what amounts to a comment for each port or group of ports.  I use this frequently.

Comment: Yeah, I knew of the port names already. I'm not looking to document in the config itself, I just want to be able to put comments into a text file that I will then paste into the console of a switch, without it screaming "unknown command" at me for every line.

I sort of figured that this was the case.